# How to get CookieManager from JMeter SampleResult

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I have a backend listener that posts JMeter results to an external server.  It works for most parts.  However, I'd like to get cookie info for failed requests.  Backend listener only gets SampleResult and I don't see an API to access cookie info from SampleResult.  Does anyone have an idea?

View Result Tree listener is able to print out request cookies, so there must be a way.  However, it's not obvious what's the class name for that particular listener.  If anyone can point me to that source code, it'll be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to help without seeing some code, but one general direction could be this: you can check if your `SampleResult` is of type [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html), and if yes, get its cookies, using `getCookies()` method. Whole process could be wrapped as the following function:

```
public String getCookiesForHttpResult(SampleResult sampleResult) {

     if (sampleResult instanceof HTTPSampleResult) {

         HTTPSampleResult httpSampleResult = (HTTPSampleResult) sampleResult;
         return httpSampleResult.getCookies();
     }

     // not HTTP result
     return null;
}
```

Something like that is done in JMeter's [RequestViewHTTP.java](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/48484529/)

Getting CookieManager in backend listener can be problematic, since it's mutable: by the time backend listener reads from CookieManager, list of cookies may be different from the time of request execution.

Answer (score 1):

With current JMeter implementation it is not possible unless your create your own [AbstractBackendListenerClient](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/AbstractBackendListenerClient.html) implementation which will be cookies-aware.

Also depending on how do you parse result you can substitute a "not interesting" [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) field (for example [Response Message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)) with cookie values for failed requests. It can be done using i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    def manager = sampler.getCookieManager()
    def cookies = new StringBuilder()
    for (int i = 0; i < manager.getCookieCount(); i++) { 
        cookies.append(manager.get(i).getName()).append('=').append(manager.get(i).getValue())
    }
    prev.setResponseMessage(cookies.toString())
}
```